# finding the nth term fibonacci sequence using loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop, fibonacci

I'm just new here in Javascript and I would like to ask you question on how to make a simple fibonacci generator by which when a user input any number, it will find the nth term of the fibonacci sequence. Sample code is given.

```
<html>
<body>
the number inserted in this textbox will find the nth term of the fibonacci sequence. The sample is 4 where the 4th term is 5. 
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
var x = document.f1.n1.value;
if(x=4) {

document.write(5);
}
}
</script>
<form name="f1" onsubmit="return false">
First no. <input type="text"name="n1" value=3 disabled>
<input type="submit" value=GO onClick="myFunction()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried googling for the fibonacci algorithm.  It even comes in recursive flavors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example with recursive call:

```js
function myFunction(getLucas) {
  var x = document.f1.n1.value;
  if (getLucas) {
      alert(lucas(x));
  }
  else {
      alert(fib(x));
  }
}

function fib(n) {
  if (n < 2) {
      return n;
  }
  else {
      return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
  }
}

function lucas(n) {
  if (n < 2) {
      return 2-n;
  }
  else {
      return lucas(n - 1) + lucas(n - 2);
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="f1" onsubmit="return false">
  First no.
  <input type="text" name="n1" value="3">
  <input type="submit" value="Fibonacci" onClick="myFunction()">
  <input type="submit" value="Lucas" onClick="myFunction(true)">
</form>
```

Comment: Note, errors in your code: `x=4` is an assignment, not comparation - use `x==4` instead; try avoiding using `document.write`, but use an element and its `textContent`; your input field was disabled using the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: I'll be studying that mate since I'm only a beginner in JavaScript. Thank you for the advice. Looking forward to further examine JavaScript.

Comment: Of course, that's why I'm giving you advice on how to write better code from the start, just trying to help. :) There, I've added the Lucas sequence to the original code. You're welcome!

Comment: Judging from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number, seems like the zeroth term is 2, the first one is 1, etc. It can be easily reprogrammed if you want to start counting from 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write(getAmount(x));

function getAmount(x) {
    if(x < 3) {
        return 1;
    } else { 
        return getAmount(x - 1) + getAmount(x - 2);
    }
}
```

Not sure if all the correct notation/language but thats the logic you need.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to prove here. Can you explain to me further on what will I revise?

Comment: That function returns the fib value for x by recursively calling itself for the previous two fib values; fib = last fib value + last fib value - 1.

Comment: Well, I need a working code which I will put in my function to get it work tho. I'm still new here. Thanks in advance

Comment: And I've given you it, just some notation might need changing because I've forgotten raw javascript off the top of my head.

Comment: Why do you need `displayAmount()` for? And the `array` at the top? Also, this will return a wrong result for 0...

Comment: just a quick question, where will I add my value of x in the script above since x is the input number.

Comment: There is no fibonaci sequence for 0, the sequence starts as 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 and so on, 0 as x would return 1, which is correct.

displayAmount is something I used in my own application because I represented the current fib with stars rather than a numerical value, so it's not needed at all, just was too lazy to remove it I guess.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle can you make the var x as the input number be included in the script?

Comment: It can be 0, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number. Please remove all the irrelevant data from your answer.

Comment: You already have a value for x Codex, its in the code you provided..

As for the previous question, starting at 0, I'll admit after reading up it can be either, the original fib sequence started with 1, however lately people have been converting to use 0 as the initial start, in that case you would just have to state if(x == 0) return 0;

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved. Just what I need. Thank you mate. Quick question, can you do the same as the Lucas sequence?

Comment: I'll be honest mate, I don't even know what the Lucas sequence is. Let me read up.

EDIT: Oh, yeah, should be fairly easy to convert.